# Add password to keychain from command line without showing them

Tags: command-line, security, password, keychain

According to https://www.netmeister.org/blog/keychain-passwords.html

> Secondly, we are necessarily leaking the newly generated password into
>   the process table as the shell expands the backticks (more details
>   here). Sadly, the security(1) utility has no other method of
>   non-interactively accepting a password but on the command-line[1]. For
>   this reason, it may be preferable to create the secret using the GUI
>   application.

Is it possible to programmatically add passwords to the keychain without leaking them to the `ps -ef` output?

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and wrote a small command line app to do it for you [programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1398366-seckeychainaddgenericpassword), here it [is](https://github.com/rdp/os_x_keychain_create_pipe_in_password), finally pipe-able console password entry :)

Other options:

If you run `security add-generic-password ... -w` then it will prompt you for your password, you can type it in there, that doesn't leak anything.

There are a few hacks to [feed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79986/why-cant-i-paste-into-the-password-dialog-when-mounting-an-encrypted-disk-image) the secure prompt, but just using it is OK too (or use the GUI).

In my case (attempting to feed `kinit`) it can [integrate](https://superuser.com/q/360262/39364) with the keychain, though still a manual initial entry, built-in.